User Export Function Missing
I am trying to export my Users on Wordpress and I don't see the "Export" function under "Bulk Actions"

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

There isn't a an "Export Users" functionality in stock WordPress. If you've used a plugin for this, you'll need to contact their support team; third-party plugin support is off topic here.

You have to use Export Users for WordPress, Import and export users and customers or Export and Import Users and Customers plugin to export your wodpress users
